# g++: Compilation failed to deduce reference array in case of temporary object

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm facing the compilation error in the following code. I'm expecting that even temporary
object can be bound to const reference. So I'm wondering that it should be valid code. However, g++ gives me this error while clang will not give such an error. Does anyone let me know the exact reason why this happens?

```
#include <iostream>

struct TestClass
{
    TestClass() : str()
    {   
        strncpy(str, "hello", sizeof(str));
    }   

    char str[6];

    char (&getStr())[6]
    {   
        return str;
    }   
};

template <typename T>
void printFunc(const T& str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    TestClass obj;
    printFunc(obj.str);
//  printFunc(TestClass().str);  // <- This line gives compilation error.
    printFunc(TestClass().getStr());
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure? I used g++ and didn't get any error.

Comment: For future reference, don't use html tags to put code in your post, just select it all, then hit the `{}` button.  Or indent it by 4 spaces (in addition to normal code indentation), which is what the `{}` button does.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error with g++ 4.6.3. Of course, after uncommenting the line... What is the exact error?

Comment: g++ 4.7.1 doesn't give any error. But on older g++, the error is thrown. http://ideone.com/263aT

Comment: The error vanishes when i replace `void printFunc(const T& str)` with `void printFunc(const T str)`.

Comment: It seems that g++ compiler I'm using is quite old... 4.2.1. Maybe that's the reason it gives this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume that your version of GCC trips over the fact that `TestClass().str` is an *rvalue* array (quite an exotic thing in both C and C++ languages). Something in the specifics of reference initialization when the initailizer is an *rvalue* is implemented incorrectly. Apparently, the bug was fixed in later versions.

Meanwhile both `obj.str` and `TestClass().getStr()` are *lvalue* arrays. They are handled by the straightforward rules of direct reference binding, so the issue does not arise.

*To address the comment:*

If you modify your function template to

```
template <typename T> printFunc(const T str)
```

the situation will change drastically. Now it is no longer a reference-binding issue. Now the array-to-pointer conversion rules take over.

In your original version the type `T` was deduced as `char [6]`, while in this new one it is deduced as `char *`. Your array type is completely lost when the argument is passed to the function: it's a pointer that gets passed instead. This completely eliminates the original issue of reference binding and makes the code compile regardless of the lvalue-ness or rvalue-ness of the array.

For example, you can try printing `sizeof str` inside your function and observe the difference between the two versions. The original will print your array size in bytes (`6`), while the new one will print pointer size (`4` for ideone's platform).

Comment: The error vanishes in ideone when i replace `void printFunc(const T& str)` with `void printFunc(const T str)`. Any explanation?
http://ideone.com/ohoBZ